# Изменение размера массива C++

Tags: c++, массивы, resize, выделение-памяти, realloc

Хотелось бы получить ответ на вопрос, связанный с переопределением размера массива и дополнением его числами.
Интересует следующее:
У меня есть массив, определенного размера и заполненный числами.
Каким образом мне сделать так, чтобы я мог переопределить размер данного массива и **дополнить** его другими значениями,старые значения должны остаться.

Думаю в этом направлении-создавать временный массив, а потом из него докидывать в глобальный. Написал вот простенький код.

```
#include <iostream>

void resize(int size, int *arr) 
{
    size_t newSize = size;
    int* newArr = new int[newSize];

    memcpy(newArr, arr, size * sizeof(int));

    size = newSize;
    delete[] arr;
    arr = newArr;
}
int main()
{
    int size = 10;
    int* arr = new int[size];
    //Запись координат
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 21;
    }
    resize(size, arr);
}
```

К примеру
Массив 1={1,2,3,4,5},размер массива = 5
потом мне нужно дополнить массив числами 6,7,8,9,10 и чтобы размер был уже равен 10.
Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Используйте `std::vector`

Comment: понимаю, но нужно именно с массивами работать...

Comment: Мне кажется, что вам нужен односвязный/двусвязный список

Comment: Ну тогда никак, размер массива после создания не изменить. Можно только выделить новый массив и удалить старый.

Comment: Для простых типов (не классов) см. [man realloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc)

Answer (score 1):

Станартный `std::vector` использует 2 механизма:

- **Коэффициент приращения** (например: `capacity *= 2;`)
- **Резервирование** (`std::vector::reserve(std::size_t)`)

```cpp
void MyVector::push_back(int element) {
    if (size_ == capacity_) reserve(capacity_ * 2);
    data_[size_++] = element;
}

void MyVector::reserve(std::size_t capacity) {
    if (capacity <= capacity_) return;
    auto data = new int[capacity];
    std::memcpy(data,data_,capacity_*sizeof(int));
    delete[] data_;
    data_ = data;
    capacity_ = capacity;
}
```

Теоретически `std::realloc` должен быть эффективнее. Он может просто расширить существующий блок памяти.

```cpp
void MyVector::reserve(std::size_t capacity) {
    if (capacity <= capacity_) return;
    auto data = (int*)std::realloc(data_,capacity*sizeof(int));
    if (!data) throw std::bad_alloc{};     
    data_ = data;
    capacity_ = capacity;
}
```

Как было отмечено в комментариях, сишные функции *аллокации памяти* не могут вызывать *конструктор*, поэтому данная реализация применима только для *примитивных типов* не имеющих конструкторов. Однако, в более продвинутой реализации можно использовать *"ручное управление памятью"* с помощью *placement new* ([статья на Habr](https://habr.com/ru/companies/xakep/articles/257893/)), совмещая выделение памяти средствами ОС с помощью `std::realloc` с созданием объектов с помощью *placement new*.

В связи со множественными случаями недопонимания произошедшими в комментариях к этому ответу, вынужден отдельно отметить, что **способы аллокации и деаллокации памяти и сишными и плюсовыми методами несовместимы и являются UB**.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, зачем нужно разделение на `malloc` и `realloc` в `reserve`, ведь `realloc` просто выделит запрашиваемую память, если ему передать нулевой указатель. И зачем нужен `memcpy` после `realloc`, если последний сам копирует старые данные?  И вообще, если вызов `realloc` будет успешен, то не гарантируется работоспособность проверки `if (data_ && data != data_)`, т.к. старый указатель `data_` становится невалидным, и следовательно, не следует его читать.

Comment: @wololo, Я просто `realloc`ом не пользовался 100 лет, поэтому забыл/просмотрел, что он копирует память и делает `free`, да ещё и работает как `malloc` при `ptr == nullptr`.

Comment: `realloc` несовместим c `new`

Comment: @AlexGlebe, вообще то это альтернативный способ! А не совмещение.

Comment: `realloc` работает только с выделением памяти, а `new` вызывает конструкторы элементов. И они вообще несовместимы.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, я знаю. Но в данном случае это не то чтобы проблема. К тому же в более продвинутой реализации можно использовать realloc + placement new

Comment: Совмещение new и realloc - это UB, и на него активно ругаются санитайзеры: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/shz4drjzK

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, вы сначала прочитайте комментарии и ответ внимательнее. Я честно не понимаю, как этого можно не знать, когда это написано в любом учебнике.

Comment: Прочитал, два раза. Что я должен тут увидеть? Вы пишите, что он работает только для примитивных типов, но в моем понимании, если санитайзер на это срабатывает - это не "работает".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да нет тут смешиваия! То что выделяется `new` - освобождается `delete`, то что выделяется `{m|c|re}alloc` - освобождается `free`. Это ежу понятно.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ЭТО АЛЬТЕРНАТИВНЫЕ РЕАЛИЗАЦИИ

Comment: Не кричите. Тогда я бы в ответе явно обозначил, что если использовать realloc, то нужно все new и delete заменить на malloc и free.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать следующим образом:

Используем функцию `memset` для установки всех элементов `arr_new` в значение 0. `sizeof(int) * newSize` определяет количество байт, которые должны быть установлены в 0.

С помощью функции `copy` копируем элементы из исходного массива `arr` в новый массив `arr_new. min(oldSize, newSize)` используем для определения количества элементов, которые будут скопированы. Если новый размер `newSize` меньше старого размера `oldSize`, то копируем только первые `newSize` элементов.

```
int* Resize(int* arr, int oldSize, int newSize)
{
    int* arr_new = new int[newSize];
    memset(arr_new, 0, sizeof(int) * newSize);

    copy(arr, arr + min(oldSize, newSize), arr_new);

    delete[] arr;

    return arr_new;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ уже был дан, но я хотел бы его подтвердить цифрами.
Копировать можно через memcpy или через copy (тест далее показывает, что они идентичны).
Массив можно расширять на нужный размер, а можно на больший (и вот здесь тест показывает прирост производительности, если не делаем лишние расширения).

Результат теста в релизной сборке:
**memcpy alg: 1.393 sec, copy alg: 1.409 sec, capacity alg: 0.042 sec**

Код теста (с проверкой идентичности полученных в конце массивов):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int* resizeMemCpy(int* arr, size_t oldSize, size_t newSize) {
    int* newArr = new int[newSize];
    memset(newArr, 0, sizeof(int) * newSize);

    memcpy(newArr, arr, min(oldSize, newSize) * sizeof(int));

    delete[] arr;
    return newArr;
}

int* resizeCopy(int* arr, size_t oldSize, size_t newSize) {
    int* arr_new = new int[newSize];
    memset(arr_new, 0, sizeof(int) * newSize);

    copy(arr, arr + min(oldSize, newSize), arr_new);

    delete[] arr;
    return arr_new;
}

int* resizeCapacity(int* arr, size_t oldSize, size_t newSize, size_t* capacity) {
    if (*capacity >= newSize) {
        return arr;
    }

    size_t oldCapacity = *capacity;
    *capacity *= 2;
    auto data = new int[*capacity];
    memset(data, 0, sizeof(int) * *capacity);

    memcpy(data, arr, oldCapacity * sizeof(int));

    delete[] arr;
    return data;
}


void checkEqual(int* arr1, int* arr2, int* arr3, size_t size) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr1[i] != arr2[i]) {
            throw exception("content of arr2 not equal arr1");
        }
        if (arr1[i] != arr3[i]) {
            throw exception("content of arr3 not equal arr1");
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    try {
        const size_t initSize = 10;
        const size_t addSize = 100;
        const int N = 1000;
        const int repeat = 100;

        double clocksMemCpy = 0;
        double clocksCopy = 0;
        double clocksCapacity = 0;
        clock_t start, end;

        for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
            size_t capacity = initSize;
            int* arr1 = new int[initSize];
            int* arr2 = new int[initSize];
            int* arr3 = new int[initSize];

            for (size_t i = 0; i < initSize; i++)
            {
                arr1[i] = arr2[i] = arr3[i] = rand() % 21;
            }

            size_t size = initSize;
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                int newSize = size + addSize;

                start = clock();
                arr1 = resizeMemCpy(arr1, size, newSize);
                end = clock();
                clocksMemCpy += double(end) - start;

                start = clock();
                arr2 = resizeCopy(arr2, size, newSize);
                end = clock();
                clocksCopy += double(end) - start;

                start = clock();
                arr3 = resizeCapacity(arr3, size, newSize, &capacity);
                end = clock();
                clocksCapacity += double(end) - start;

                size = newSize;
            }

            checkEqual(arr1, arr2, arr3, size);

            delete[] arr1;
            delete[] arr2;
            delete[] arr3;
        }

        cout << "initial size: " << initSize << ", add size: " << addSize << ", iterations: " << N << ", repeat: " << repeat
            << ", memcpy alg: " << clocksMemCpy / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " sec"
            << ", copy alg: " << clocksCopy / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " sec"
            << ", capacity alg: " << clocksCapacity / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " sec"
            << endl;

    }
    catch (const exception& ex) {
        cerr << ex.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```